# For $1 \le i \lt j \le n$ and $d=j-1$, prove $S_n = \langle\{i\;\; \overline {i+d} : 1 \le i \le n\}\rangle$ $\iff$ $gcd(d,n) = 1$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, gcd-and-lcm, free-groups, permutation-cycles

So in the first part of the question I had to prove that $gcd(d,n)=1 \implies S_n = \langle\{(i\;\; \overline {i+d}) : 1 \le i \le n\}\rangle$ whilst $\forall a \in \mathbb {Z}$,
we mark $\overline {a}$ as the only number in $\{1,2...n\}$ that satisfies $a \equiv \overline {a}\;(mod n)$.

Now for the second part which is the question I have posted I began to lose ground.

We have seen in class the following relation as to the constructor groups of $S_n$:

$S_n = \langle\{(i\;j) |\;1\le i \lt j \le n\}\rangle=\langle\{(i\;i+1)|\;1\le i \le n-1\}\rangle=\langle\{(1\;i) |\;2\le i \le n\}\rangle=\langle(1\;2),(1\;2\;3...n)\rangle$

I'm very much lost on the conncection between gcd(d,n) and the constructor group and would love some help!

Comment: Use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.